# Invalid conversion from throwing function of type in swift

Tags: ios, swift, api

I am getting this error in api and here is api

Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(AFDataResponse<Data?>) throws -> Void' (aka '(DataResponse<Optional, AFError>) throws -> ()') to non-throwing function type '(AFDataResponse<Data?>) -> Void' (aka '(DataResponse<Optional, AFError>) -> ()')

```
func UploadData(vc:UIViewController,params: [String : Any],img:UIImage, url: String, header: HTTPHeaders, completionhandler:((Int,Any) -> ())?)  {
    AF.upload(
           multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
               multipartFormData.append(img.jpegData(
                   compressionQuality: 0.5)!,
                   withName: "photo",
                   fileName: "photo.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg"
               )
               for param in params {
                   let value = (param.value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
                   multipartFormData.append(value, withName: param.key)
               }
           },
           to: url,
           method: .post ,
           headers: header
       )
       .response { response in
           switch response.result {
           case .success(let value):
               var b = [String:Any]()
               do{
               let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: value!, options: []) as? [String : Any]
                   b = json ?? [String:Any]()
                   print(b)
               }
               catch{ print("erroMsg") }
               let status = b["status"]
               let data = b["data"]
               print(status ?? 0)
              
                   let toDos = try JSONDecoder().decode([UpdateModel].self, from: value!)
               
               if status as! Int == 1
               {
                   print("status \(status!) founded")
                   completionhandler?(status as! Int,toDos )
               }
               else
               { print("Invalid data entered") }
               
           case .failure(_):
               print("failed to upload data")
           }

    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: `let toDos = try JSONDecoder().decode([UpdateModel].self, from: value!)`: There is no `do`/`catch` there. You did one for `let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: value!, options: [])`, but not for that `try`

Comment: How much of the error message do you understand because this is very much what this question is about, learning to interpret and understand the compiler error?

Comment: if i add let toDos = try JSONDecoder().decode([UpdateModel].self, from: value!): in do try catch it gives error, when it reach at todo statements to moves out from do block and enter into catch block.

Comment: And what's the `error` thrown? It should give you info, did you print the error? Don't do it like `catch { print("erroMsg") }`, print the error: `catch { print("erroMsg: \(error)") }`

Comment: typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Please update your code to reflect the changes you made according to the comments you received. Please add the model your are trying to decode to, `UpdateModel` in your case. And an example `JSON` so we can see what´s wrong with your code.